# Can I use Selenium Python to draw on a canvas?

Tags: python, selenium, canvas, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest

I am trying to run automated tests and benchmarks for an HTML5 canvas app.  I have set up Selenium with python-unittest and ChromeDriver (though I'm open to alternatives).

The canvas app is a whiteboard where lines are drawn by clicking the mouse and dragging around on the canvas. How can I automate drawing simple shapes with Selenium? I've browsed through the python-selenium API and the only mouse movement testing options are through `ActionChains`, but these all move the mouse to elements based on their `id` or `class`. I haven't seen a way to automate mouse movements based on coordinates on a canvas.

Is there any way to achieve automated testing of drawing on a canvas?

Comment: Maybe PyUserInput could help: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyUserInput/0.1.9 With it you can control mouse movements/clicking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a click_and_hold function as well. This worked for me:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

canvas = self.driver.find_element_by_id("myCanvas")
drawing = ActionChains(self.driver)\
    .click_and_hold(canvas)\
    .move_by_offset(-10, -15)\
    .move_by_offset(20, 32)\
    .move_by_offset(10, 25)\
    .release()
drawing.perform()
```

(Where self.driver is my Selenium webdriver.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I should read a little more of the docs before asking my questions.  There are several `ActionChains` that could be used to shoehorn the needed testing, such as:

- [`drag_and_drop_by_offset(source, xoffset, yoffset)`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.drag_and_drop_by_offset)
- [`move_by_offset(xoffset, yoffset)`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_by_offset)
- [`move_to_element(to_element)`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_to_element)
- [`move_to_element_with_offset(to_element, xoffset, yoffset)`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_to_element_with_offset)